# EmberJs: Component action not triggered in pagination example

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I followed this pagination tutorial but can't get the "next-page" / "prev page" to work. http://webcloud.info/blog/2014/11/01/building-a-real-world-pagination-with-ember-js-the-right-way/

JSBIN - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/manetavule/2/

The alert never runs in the click event, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Myapp.PaginatonBaseComponent = Ember.Component.extend({  
 tagName: 'button',
 classNames: 'btn btn-default'.w(),
 attributeBindings: ['disabled'],
 enabled: true,
 disabled: Ember.computed.not('enabled'),
 action: null,
 click: function(){
  alert('not triggered!');
  this.sendAction();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The name of your component is misspelled.

   Instead of

   `Myapp.PaginatonBaseComponent = Ember.Component.extend({`

   it should be

   `Myapp.PaginationBaseComponent = Ember.Component.extend({`
2. Your (component) button(s) are disabled. The reason for this is that you are passing in `enabled` property with the value of `false` Your `disabled` property is thus set to the opposite of your `enabled` property, which makes it `true` and your button becomes disabled and therefore `click` event is not being run.

   I fixed both issues in the following jsbin by 1) spelling the component name correctly and 2) explicitly setting `disabled` property to `false` (for now) so that you can see that now `click` handler is indeed being called.

http://jsbin.com/cuqada/1/edit?html,js,output